# Execute a code when the template is loaded

Tags: ember.js

I want to execute a simple action when the DOM is ready. I tried to use `on('init')` but it's triggered before the template is loaded. I saw some options for components but I don't use a component.

Here is the code I have :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  onTemplateLoaded: function() {
    console.log('message')
  }.on('init')
})
```

Very simple. My question is basic but I don't find the solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to do something on a particular route you'd currently end up with `views/index.js`

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this._super();
    this.$().append("<h1>hi</h1>");
  }
});
```

See: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kegere/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: View objects works with Ember "1.13"? I don't see it in the guide.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way ? Ember 1.13 does not seem to like that.

Comment: @Dougui My jsbin is ember 1.13, so yes, demonstrably. I'm not sure why views aren't mentioned in 1.13, but controllers are being replaced for 2.0 with components. In which case you would end up with the virtually same code, replacing Ember.View with Ember.Component and explicitly stating the component in your template, or using a routable component.

Comment: As shown is the doc "Views have been removed in Ember 2.0. Components, which provide better isolation and scoping semantics, fulfill the use-cases views were introduced for.". I will use components. It seems to be more stable.